# Creating a symmetrical 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I've been racking my brains over something that must be incredibly simple, as I've not seen it answered anywhere (or I'm very bad at searching).

I want to create a symmetrical 2D array, filled with random numbers from 1 to 100 inclusive... here is what I've got so far

int n = 3;
        int rangeOfWeights = 100;

```
    double[][] array = new double[n][n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            array[i][j] = rand.nextInt((rangeOfWeights)+1);         
        }
    }
```

At the moment, this is giving results like:

```
44 45 32 
9 31 53 
25 48 74
```

when actually the kind of result I want is:

```
0 34 32
34 0 23
32 23 0
```

Comment: Symmetrical how? There are many kinds of symmetries.

Comment: Apologies, symmetrical as in [i][j] == [j][i]

Comment: Then why don't you = with [j][i] then? (and use proper bounds)

Comment: PBCAK? Meaning? EDIT: I understand. But I really can't find the answer to this anywhere else, and as a beginner I'm not sure at which stage I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you defined, you're trying to create a 2D array where `array[i][j] == array[j][i]`. You could a pair of nested loops where one iterates up to the array's size and the other up to the outer array's counter, and in each iteration set the value of the two symmetrical values:

```
double[][] array = new double[n][n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        int value = rand.nextInt((rangeOfWeights)+1);         
        array[i][j] = value;
        array[j][i] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was vastly helpful. I suppose if I want for every i == j to entry to be 0, I just add an if statement within the for loop?

Comment: no need to add a if condition, inner for loop condition is j<i, so i==j elements will be not assigned by the for loop, default value will remain as 0;

Comment: @hunter You're absolutely right - I missed that detail. Thanks